# Why does printing a packed int freak out OS X?

Tags: python, macos

When printing a binary packed nonce in the terminal, it generates a bunch of alerts.

The code of the program is:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
import hashlib
import sys

print "Input the message you want to work on:"
message = raw_input()
orig_hash = hashlib.sha512(message).digest()

trialValue = 99999999999999999999
target = 4103215547750
nonce = 0
while trialValue > target:
nonce += 1
packed_nonce = pack('>Q', nonce)

print packed_nonce

trialValue, = unpack('>Q',hashlib.sha512(packed_nonce + orig_hash).digest()[0:8])

print nonce
print trialValue
```

This isn't a big deal, but does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You should post the code here

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem without directing us to a YouTube video?

Comment: please write a question and don't bother making videos.

Comment: I have done what you've requested. I just felt I could better explain it with a video. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because some of the data you're printing contains a BEL (0x07) character, which causes the terminal to beep.

Don't print control characters unless you want the terminal to do weird things.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Pretty sure that's what's happening. I'll try filtering that char out and see what happens.

Comment: You should really just filter out all control characters (character codes not between `0x20` and `0x7e`), or not print raw data.